# Link Behind Image with margins

Tags: html, image

Trying to add a link behind this image but every time I do, the margin I have setup in the class is broken

```css
.sponsors img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="images/sponsor-hilltop.png" width="100px" height="auto" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

try to use z index or

```
*{margin:0px;
     }
```